# Login page doesn't position correctly on bigger screen - React Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have this Login Form which is created by using React Bootstrap. The form works well in my computer but when I have the form on a bigger screen, it leaves a big space between the form and the navbar. Is there any way to correct it so it can display properly on any screen size? I included the picture with the description to help you have a better view of the problem, thank you

[image]

This is my Login Form code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import "./Login.css";


export default function Login() {
  return (
    <>
    <Menu />
    <div className="Login">
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="email">
          <Form.Control
            autoFocus
            type="email"
            value={email}
            placeholder="Please enter your email"
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="password">
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            value={password}
            placeholder="Please enter your password"
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <a href="forget.html" className="forgot-password">
          Forgot Password?
        </a>
        <Button block size="lg" type="submit" disabled={!validateForm()}>
          Sign In
        </Button>
        <Button block size="lg" type="submit">
          Sign Up
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is Login CSS:

```
body {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
background: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/f0328534-9c08-4f7a-867f-48d6314fffae%2Fchewy-DR6wPYR2DRc-unsplash.jpg?v=1603075265987")
  no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}  

@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
    .Login {
      padding: 60px 0;
      margin-top: 120px;
    }


.Login form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 320px;
}


}
  
  Form {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 24px;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  
  Form h2 {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #555555;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 47px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
  
  .form-control {
    height: 54px;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
  }
  
  .forgot-password {
    padding: 2px;
  }
  
  .Login button {
    margin-top: 24px;
    background-color: #555555;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  
  .Login button:hover {
    background: #a64bf4;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #00dbde, #fc00ff);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #00dbde, #fc00ff);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #00dbde, #fc00ff);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00dbde, #fc00ff);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
  }
  
  .Login form label {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the relational margin property in your css

```
.Login {
   padding: 60px 0;
   margin-top: 4.5rem;
}
```

When you use rem, the css set property depend on screen size. Use fixed margin-top with px.

```
.Login {
   padding: 60px 0;
   margin-top: 400px;
}
```

Comment: The problem happened because I used the px, then I changed it to rem, however the problem is not solved